# how to subscribe to python requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I need an alternative mecahnism to kafka where my python module will publish message to a topic(as callback url) and javascript wil subscribe these messages and do processing accordingly.How can I achieve this?I need to create a messaging api(REST Api) in Javascript,I will provide api url as callbackurl to python module so that python module can send messages to this call backurl

Comment: I think you've answered your own question, create a REST API :-)

Comment: I need rest api in js to act as callback and python module will be called  with this callbackurl.I designed a restapi ,when python module calls it only first call is retrieved in rest api code in js

Comment: yup, you got it! Stack Overflow is not your personal code monkey, so start writing your app, then come back to us with questions and we'll be happy to help you!

Comment: PubNub is the solution I guess